# Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite foreign key constraint error after OneStepCheckout Module install

Tags: magento2.2.4, catalog-url-rewrite

Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'lampesecoenergie2/CAT_URL_REWRITE_PRD_CTGR_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID' to system tables
```

After OneStepCheckout Module enable

And run the setup:upgrade `php bin/magento setup:upgrade;` got error

Now site is working but setup:upgrade `php bin/magento setup:upgrade;` run we got the error

Comment: Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout Module ??

Comment: i disable the Module site is working but  'php bin/magento setup:upgrade;'  run the code i get error

Comment: run first the di:compile

Comment: i try this also but error is same @magefms

Comment: https://www.onestepcheckout.com/  OneStepCheckout Module @RkRathod

Comment: in setup_module delete onestepcheckout module entry in try to setup:upgrade

Comment: i deleted OneStepCheckout Module  already but error is same